Why does majorization (preorder on vectors) use $\prec$ instead of $\preceq$?
Since the preorder $\prec$ is reflexive, this seems to make it unnecessarily harder to differentiate it from strict majorization.
E.g. surely there are results out there, where majorization implies an inequality which is strict if and only if the majoriziation is strict, in which one succinctly could work with $\prec$ as strict majorization, making the notation a little easier.
Why hasn't $\preceq$, or at least $\lesssim$ established itself instead of $\prec$?

It is just notational preference. The same matter is the case with subset relations too, i.e., $\subset$ vs. $\subseteq$.
It has become standard that, in general, $\subset \; \equiv \; \subseteq$, as well as $\prec \; \equiv \; \preceq$.
If strictness is desired to be emphasized, then the symbol that is commonly used is $\subsetneq$ for the subset relation. I do not know whether a similar symbol exists for strict majorization.

I've actually been under the impression that newer text start to gravitate towards $\subseteq$. Yes, there might exist a symbol $\precneq$, but since there are elements differing from $x$ which can not be distinguished by $\prec$, $\precneq$ feels ambiguos in the sense that I'm not sure whether it only excludes $(x,x)$ from the relation, or for all permutations $x_P$ the tuple $(x,x_P)$ as well
